# array declration methods in php

Tags: php, arrays

i have array like this, where i have maintaining a index that is the position and there is two field which should be update

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [text2] => Banner ads
        [price2] => 297
    )

 )
```

now i want to insert another element like a way that look like

```
 Array
    (
    [1] => Array
    (
        [text2] => logo
        [price2] => 300
    )

  )
```

what would be the best way to do so??? please suggest me?

Comment: ... or see [array_push()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Comment: i have already seen this, but this cant help me out

Answer (score 3):

```
$array[] = array('text2' => 'logo', 'price2' => 300)
```

Comment: or in php 5.4 $array[] = ['text2' => 'logo', 'price2' => 300]

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in C:\xampp\htdocs\adam\order.php on line 24

Comment: $array[] = array('text2' => 'logo', 'price2' => 300)

i have successfully used ur code, but its always stores data in 0th position, i want to add data to be insert after the next vacant position not to overlap the previous 0th position, what should i do?